# Console application, first webrequest doesn't get response, later does, why?

Tags: c#, api, console-application, webrequest, veracode

I am developing console application for API integration. This follow fetching token in first request and then getting report in second request after passing token.

```
string token = GetToken(app_id); // API call, which is working fine and getting token
string reportquerystring = "path?token=" + token;

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@reportquerystring);
req.Method = "GET";
req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + 
    Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));
var resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;


using (Stream downloadstream = resp.GetResponseStream())
{
    XmlDocument reportxml = new XmlDocument();
    string filename = "location\\";
    string reportxmlString = (new StreamReader(downloadstream)).ReadToEnd();
    reportxml.LoadXml(reportxmlString);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(reportxml);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename + "data_" + app_id + ".txt", json);
}
```

Here when I run this code while debugging, on the first call of download report, response xml is empty, when I drag debugger again before call, in the same run, then it gets response properly. But until and unless I figure out the reason why first call to download report API is not working or how I can make it work, I can not proceed.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Just trying to understand. So you basically run the function and see no xml data, but then if you check the debugger after bit you see the xml data without calling the function again?

Comment: No, When I see no xml data in variable, I drag debugger to second step of the code, re-running the following steps in the same run, then I get xml response.

Comment: I tried that but no luck.